# Is it possible to create WebGL programs with only vertex shaders?

Tags: webgl2

I'm getting a "missing shader" error when I try to link a WebGL2 shader program with only vertex shaders attached. I'm trying to use Transform Feedback, and I thought that since the output of the vertex shader is written out, there should not be a need for a fragment shader.

From this blog post: [link](http://prideout.net/blog/?tag=opengl-transform-feedback) it seems that you should be able to do this. Is there something special about WebGL that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebGL 2 is based on OpenGL ES 3.0 which per specification requires vertex and fragment shaders to be present on program objects:

> Linking can fail for a variety of reasons as specified in the OpenGL
>   ES Shading Language Specification, as well as any of the following
>   reasons:
>
> - [...]
> - **program does not contain both a vertex shader and a
>     fragment shader**.

*[OpenGL ES 3.0 Specification, Page 49](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf#nameddest=section-6.1.12)*

You may attach a simple solid color or discarding fragment shader instead.